# SQL, filter out same Id's if null exists

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following query:

```
SELECT        
    m.MilgaId, 
    opt.PropertyId, 
    sd.PropOptionId
FROM            
    Milga AS m INNER JOIN
    PropertyOptionInMilga AS poInMil ON m.MilgaId = poInMil.MilgaId INNER JOIN
    PropertyOption AS opt on poInMil.PropertyOptionId = opt.PropertyOptionId LEFT JOIN
    StudentData AS sd on sd.UserId = 'A270D9AC-0D73-4E01-8CBC-D3C5812CCA97' 
AND opt.PropertyId = sd.PropertyId
    GROUP BY 
        m.MilgaId, 
        opt.PropertyId, 
        sd.PropOptionId, 
        m.IsEnable
    HAVING  
        (m.IsEnable = 1)
    ORDER BY 
        m.MilgaId
```

**Query result:**

```
MilgaId PropertyId  PropOptionId
937       90            2291
937       132           2434
938       25            38
938       91            NULL        <-----
938       132           2434
```

I would to filter out all `MilgaId` with the same Id if one of them is `null` -  all the rows for `milgaId=938` should be filtered out.

**My query result should look like:**

```
MilgaId PropertyId  PropOptionId
937       90            2291
937       132           2434
```

*** ***Correction:**

Query result:

```
MilgaId PropertyId  PropOptionId
937       90            2291
937       132           null       <-----  132 with null
937       132           2434       <-----  132 has one without null so it's in result
938       25            38
938       91            NULL        <----- 
938       132           2434
939       201           2600
939       202           null
```

** Each `milgaId` must have all `PropertyId` with at least one `PropOptionId` `not null`

**My query result should look like:**

```
MilgaId PropertyId  PropOptionId
937       90            2291
937       132           2434
```

Comment: Are you sure you want that LEFT JOIN?

Comment: I think most coders would put search conditions in a `WHERE` clause for clarity e.g. `sd.UserId = 'A270D9AC-0D73-4E01-8CBC-D3C5812CCA97'` and `m.IsEnable = 1`.

Comment: `Each milgaId must have all PropertyId with at least one PropOptionId not null` ... then why is`938` being filtered out?  You need to clean up your logic here.

Comment: 938 is out because for PropertyId=91 there is no PropOptionId (just null). While 973 is In because [90: 2291], [132: 2434]

Answer (score 1):

```
WITH CTE (MilgaId, PropertyId, PropOptionId, IsEnable)
AS
(
SELECT m.MilgaId, 
       opt.PropertyId, 
       sd.PropOptionId,
       m.IsEnable
FROM            
    Milga AS m
INNER JOIN
PropertyOptionInMilga AS poInMil
    ON m.MilgaId = poInMil.MilgaId
INNER JOIN
PropertyOption AS opt
    ON poInMil.PropertyOptionId = opt.PropertyOptionId
LEFT JOIN
StudentData AS sd
    ON sd.UserId = 'A270D9AC-0D73-4E01-8CBC-D3C5812CCA97' AND
       opt.PropertyId = sd.PropertyId
)

SELECT t1.MilgaId, 
       t1.PropertyId, 
       t1.PropOptionId
FROM CTE t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT t.MilgaId
    FROM CTE t
    GROUP BY t.MilgaId
    HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN t.PropOptionId IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0
) t2
    ON t1.MilgaId = t2.MilgaId
GROUP BY 
    t1.MilgaId, 
    t1.PropertyId, 
    t1.PropOptionId, 
    t1.IsEnable
HAVING  
    (t1.IsEnable = 1) AND
ORDER BY 
    t1.MilgaId
```

Comment: I am still getting MilgaId=938. those with null where removed but not others with same milgaId

Comment: I had a mistake. can you take a look the correction section? Thank you!

Comment: @Eyal I have updated again, it was just a small change to the `HAVING` clause.

Comment: it does not work well. I need only rows of MilgaId when each propertyId has at least one propOptionId=no null. in my sample results 937 is listed because it has at least one PropOptionId for each PropertyId. 939 is not listed because Propertyid=202 does not have not null value. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

Yo can add one more condition (check performance)

```
  AND m.MilgaId NOT IN(SELECT DISTINCT  poInMil.MilgaId 
PropertyOptionInMilga AS poInMil  INNER JOIN
PropertyOption AS opt ON poInMil.PropertyOptionId = opt.PropertyOptionId 
LEFT JOIN  StudentData AS sd ON sd.UserId = 'A270D9AC-0D73-4E01-8CBC-D3C5812CCA97' AND opt.PropertyId = sd.PropertyId 
WHERE sd.PropertyId IS NULL)
```

like this :

```
SELECT        
    m.MilgaId, 
    opt.PropertyId, 
    sd.PropOptionId
FROM            
    Milga AS m INNER JOIN
    PropertyOptionInMilga AS poInMil ON m.MilgaId = poInMil.MilgaId INNER JOIN
    PropertyOption AS opt ON poInMil.PropertyOptionId = opt.PropertyOptionId LEFT JOIN
    StudentData AS sd ON sd.UserId = 'A270D9AC-0D73-4E01-8CBC-D3C5812CCA97' 
AND opt.PropertyId = sd.PropertyId

AND m.MilgaId NOT IN(SELECT DISTINCT  poInMil.MilgaId 
PropertyOptionInMilga AS poInMil  INNER JOIN
PropertyOption AS opt ON poInMil.PropertyOptionId = opt.PropertyOptionId 
LEFT JOIN  StudentData AS sd ON sd.UserId = 'A270D9AC-0D73-4E01-8CBC-D3C5812CCA97' AND opt.PropertyId = sd.PropertyId 
WHERE sd.PropertyId IS NULL)
    GROUP BY 
        m.MilgaId, 
        opt.PropertyId, 
        sd.PropOptionId, 
        m.IsEnable
    HAVING  
        (m.IsEnable = 1)
    ORDER BY 
        m.MilgaId
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
SELECT        
    m.MilgaId, 
    opt.PropertyId, 
    sd.PropOptionId
FROM            
    Milga AS m INNER JOIN
    PropertyOptionInMilga AS poInMil ON m.MilgaId = poInMil.MilgaId INNER JOIN
    PropertyOption AS opt on poInMil.PropertyOptionId = opt.PropertyOptionId LEFT JOIN
    StudentData AS sd on sd.UserId = 'A270D9AC-0D73-4E01-8CBC-D3C5812CCA97' AND opt.PropertyId = sd.PropertyId
WHERE sd.PropOptionId IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY 
    m.MilgaId, 
    opt.PropertyId, 
    sd.PropOptionId, 
    m.IsEnable

HAVING  
    (m.IsEnable = 1)

ORDER BY 
    m.MilgaId
```

Comment: it removes the null's but not all others with same MilgaId

Answer (score 0):

Here is my take on the issue

```
SELECT        
    m.MilgaId, 
    opt.PropertyId, 
    sd.PropOptionId
FROM Milga AS m
INNER JOIN PropertyOptionInMilga AS poInMil on (m.MilgaId = poInMil.MilgaId)
INNER JOIN PropertyOption AS opt on (poInMil.PropertyOptionId = opt.PropertyOptionId)
LEFT JOIN StudentData AS sd on (sd.UserId = 'A270D9AC-0D73-4E01-8CBC-D3C5812CCA97' AND opt.PropertyId = sd.PropertyId)
left join (
select MilgaId from milga m
INNER JOIN PropertyOptionInMilga AS poInMil on (m.MilgaId = poInMil.MilgaId)
INNER JOIN PropertyOption AS opt on (poInMil.PropertyOptionId = opt.PropertyOptionId)
LEFT JOIN StudentData AS sd on (sd.UserId = 'A270D9AC-0D73-4E01-8CBC-D3C5812CCA97' AND opt.PropertyId = sd.PropertyId and sd.PropOptionId is null)) m2
on (m.MilgaId = m2.MilgaId)
where m2.MilgaId is null
    GROUP BY 
        m.MilgaId, 
        opt.PropertyId, 
        sd.PropOptionId, 
        m.IsEnable
    HAVING  
        (m.IsEnable = 1)
    ORDER BY 
        m.MilgaId
```

I am unfortunately not able to test it on an SQL Server.
So let me know if anything fails :)

Answer (score 0):

I dont know what value that `sd.PropOptionId` can be but I imagin this value must more than 0 So. I try this query (but I not test)

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT        
        m.MilgaId, 
        opt.PropertyId, 
        sd.PropOptionId,
        MIN(ISNULL(sd.PropOptionId,-99)) OVER (PARTITION BY m.MilgaId) AS [minVal]
    FROM            
        Milga AS m INNER JOIN
        PropertyOptionInMilga AS poInMil ON m.MilgaId = poInMil.MilgaId INNER JOIN
        PropertyOption AS opt on poInMil.PropertyOptionId = opt.PropertyOptionId LEFT JOIN
        StudentData AS sd on sd.UserId = 'A270D9AC-0D73-4E01-8CBC-D3C5812CCA97' 
    AND opt.PropertyId = sd.PropertyId
    WHERE m.IsEnable = 1
    ORDER BY 
        m.MilgaId
) q
WHERE q.minVal > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I went with different approach:

```
Select milgaId, MilgaName from 
    (
        SELECT   m.milgaId,m.MilgaName, count(distinct(opt.PropertyId)) as CntPropertyIdInMilga
        FROM            Milga AS m INNER JOIN
                                 PropertyOptionInMilga AS poInMil ON m.MilgaId = poInMil.MilgaId INNER JOIN
                                 PropertyOption AS opt ON poInMil.PropertyOptionId = opt.PropertyOptionId
        WHERE        (m.IsEnable = 1) AND 
                    (m.IsSpecial = 0)
        group by m.Milgaid,m.MilgaName
    )  
As tbl
    Where 
    (
        SELECT         count(distinct(sd.PropertyId))  as PropertyInStudentData
        FROM            Milga AS m INNER JOIN
                                 PropertyOptionInMilga AS poInMil ON m.MilgaId = poInMil.MilgaId INNER JOIN
                                 PropertyOption AS opt ON poInMil.PropertyOptionId = opt.PropertyOptionId INNER JOIN
                                 StudentData AS sd ON opt.PropertyOptionId = sd.PropOptionId AND sd.UserId = 'A8F60C49-960F-4A6D-A759-925077607C5A'
        WHERE        
                    (m.IsEnable = 1) AND 
                    (m.IsSpecial = 0)  AND
                    (m.MilgaId = tbl.MilgaId)
        group by m.Milgaid
    )  = CntPropertyIdInMilga
```